# octave 4.4.0 on jupyter notebook for windows 10 dies

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

On bringing up octave 4.4.0 for anaconda 3 Jupyter Notebook on windows 10
the 1st octave-gui.exe system error is:
The code execution cannot proceed becuase liboctave-5.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
Octave 4.4.0 runs in the gui by itself but not with jupyter Notebook.
Using Python 3.6.5 which runs in Jupyter Notebook.
I was able to run Octave 4.0.1 in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Install was done using conda and not pip

Comment: # packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
metakernel                0.20.14                    py_0    conda-forge
metakernel                0.20.14                   <pip>

Comment: Octave runs in Jupyter Notebook if OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE
is made equal to octave_cli.exe

Comment: This was solved by blink103 in github....the link is https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel/issues/136.

Comment: Please close this ticket